# Do the Salmon Run enemies get harder with each round?

Tags: splatoon-2

Under the same conditions (without events), are enemies harder in round 3 than in round 1?

Do enemies in round 3 take a few more hits? Are there more enemy bosses? Or are different rounds (excluding events) the same?

Comment: The same guide I linked in my other answer to one of your questions believes that the higher your pay grade, the higher the difficulty as well harder enemy spawns and more frequency boss encounters.

Comment: That I got, but here I'm asking in the same match, is Round 1 different than Round 3?

Comment: I think that the later rounds have bosses spawn more often, making it easier to ge overrun by bosses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only the paycheck of the workers that influence how the difficulty is.
Ex: If you are a Part-Timer then the rounds will be easier then if you were a Trainee. If you survive until the next round then the boss salmonoids will despawn. The difficulty between rounds is always the same unless a player messes it up.

Edit: The difficulty between round is random because of events Ex: One round is High tide, Round 2 is The Griller And round 3 is Cohock Charge.

Comment: Dont see how it explains the difference between round 1 and round 3 in the same match?

Comment: it is always the same difficulty between rounds

Comment: Any source on this?

Comment: just me playing salmon run